# MySQL Workbench Unhandled exception: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1022: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, non-ascii-characters, data-import

I am constantly facing this issue when importing .csv files into the database. I am getting the following error:

```
Unhandled exception: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1022: ordinal not in range(128)

Check the log for more details.
```

In the beginning, it was enough to change the encoding with CotEditor to Unicode (UTF-8) as I am operating on Mac, however, lately, the only way how to fix it is to send the document to a laptop operating on Windows, open it in Excel there and send it back to my Mac. Then it will upload without any issues (at least it worked so far).

I am sure, this has to be some issue on my laptop but from what I found as solutions seems like I have everything set well in the database and in the correct encoding format.

Is there anyone facing the same issue who was able to fix it for good so I don't have to send the document between different computer operational systems?

Changing encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: Have you tried converting it in "Unicode (UTF-8) with BOM" with CotEditor?

Comment: Something is set to ascii instead of utf8.

Comment: If it is a BOM, then you have a worse problem [Double encoding](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#bom_byte_order_mark)

Comment: Download old Workbench version 8.0.21 and the problem will be gone. Not sure why this isn't fixed...

Answer (score 1):

I make sure my csv file is utf-8, but I still get the error, finally, I open  mysql-workbench in terminal and solve it.

to run MySql Workbench from the command line
open /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app